# How to make function repeat x amount of times that user chose in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I got stuck with a simple task to make function run multiple times depending on what number did the user choose. I got like 1000 lines of javascript code with nested functions, so I cant really modify a lot, but here is the simplified version how I think it works:

```
function getScales() {
  getOrderData()
} 
getOrderdata() { }

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#continue").click(function () {
   getScales()
  }
});
```

As I understand, the **getScales** function measures weight of the package user put on the scales and then **getOrderData** is filling this information in the popup window. There is also a bit of jQuery code in the same file, I think it checks if the weight is not 0 and then it shows button **"continue"**.

Anyway, I need to add the dropdown menu to the **getOrderData** function (it needs to be in the popup window) of like how many items do you need to scale. If user choose 1, then the code needs to run as it is right now. If user choose for example 3, then I need to loop the code to run 3 times. First time in this loop the code will run exactly the same as right now or as if you choose 1 in the dropdown. Second and third time  it have to skip the **getOrderData** and perform only the part that happens after user clicks **"continue"**, because user dont need to see the popup anymore. Here is what I did so far, but I got stuck, cant figure out the logic how to make this thing work:

```
    function getScales() {
      if(dropdownIndex == 0){ //if user choose 1 then the process doesn't change
        getOrderData()
      } else {
      repeatTimes(times); //I'm not sure if I need to create for loop or if I can pass the value from the dropdown as a parameter "times" somehow
      }
    } 


getOrderdata() { 

var select = document.getElementById("numOfPieces"); //selecting html element and adding  dropdown options with JS
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; // I chose to do it this way so I could select dropdown options based on their array index
  
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var opt = options[i];
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
  }

  let times = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; //This is how I store the selected dropdown option in the variable 
 }


    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#continue").click(function repeatTimes() {
        getScales()
      }
    });
```

Comment: Where is `getScales()` executed?

Comment: @RoMilton Oh, it's inside of $("#continue").click(function () { }, I will edit the question rn

Comment: There looks to be some circular logic there: the Continue button executes a function `repeatTimes()`, which executes `getScales()`, which executes `repeatTimes()` again. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: @RoMilton I'm not really sure, I just named the function repeatTimes because I hope this way I can pass the index of whatever user chose in the dropdown and also since I need to skip the getOrderData if user chose number more then 1

Comment: Have you considered recursion?

Comment: I'd love to help, but I think there's some issues with the code design. If the user selects any option in the dropdown and clicks continue, then `getScales()` executes `getOrderData()`, which will then add more options to the dropdown. That doesn't seem right. If you describe exactly how it should work from the user's perspective, I can suggest a different code design.

Comment: @PeterKA I need to read about it, I have no idea what is it, I'm like very junior level right now. Do you think it is suitable for my situation?

Comment: @RoMilton this is like 1000 lines of someone else working code with bunch of api, http requests and some dark magic that I need to modify. I dont think I can like redesign a lot. But from user's perspective, they put the package to the scales and type order number to input. Then there is a popup with all their package info (thats where I need to add the dropdown so they would supposubly choose if they need to scale more then 1 package) then they click continue, there is shipment page and print label. If they got more then 1 package after label is printed it needs to return them to the shipment

Comment: @RoMilton So lets say you need to ship 2 boxes. you would put your order number in the input and weight your first box, then in the popup window you will choose 2 in the dropdown. You click continue, then on shipment page it will be like box #1 and its info, and customers shipping below. Then it takes you to print label, you do that and then you put another box to the scales. Since you chose 2 boxes it will automatically take you back to the shipping page and it will display box #1...; box #2... and then you print label. This is how my boss wants it

Answer (score 0):

If you want the the following:

1. User selects a number from a select list, eg **3**
2. User clicks button **Continue**
3. Some function is executed 3 times.

That's pretty simple, can be done with `Array.from()` and `forEach()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#continue").click(function(){
    const times = parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value, 10);
    Array.from({ length: times }).forEach(function(_, i){
      // execute some function
      someFunction(i);
    });
  });
});
```

That's the quick answer to your question. Unfortunately I can't help you with your complete flow. I understand you need to display various screens after the **Continue** is clicked, but I would need a deeper understanding of your codebase to help with that. If you need your code design looked at, you can post more of your code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Good luck.